# How can I reorganize a list of strings based on a number inside of said string?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, sorting

I am trying to create a scoreboard for my geography quiz app that I'm making. I am trying to organize the scores by the largest to the smallest and I have no idea where to even start. Here is the code for the submit button function:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Submit Button
    {
        if(isDone)
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path+"/score.txt");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path+"/score.txt");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line != null && line.Length > 0) {sw.WriteLine("\n"+ line); }
            }
            sw.WriteLine("Score:" + score +" ~"+ textBox1.Text + " -- " + label9.Text + " -- " + numCorrect + "/41" );
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

I would like to sort it by the score variable and a number that is grabbed from the line in the text file

Comment: Where `score` variable is taken from?, and how it is related to each line? cannot find it in your example.

Comment: Just sort the array [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2).  You'll need to add a custom converter or convert the array to integers to get a numeric sort.  Also, you'll need to substring (or parse somehow) the score from the line if the line doesn't just contain the score.

Comment: Each array placement contains a whole line of information not just the score

`lines[1]` contains `Score:2 ~Type name once done -- Timer: 00:02 -- 4/41
` (my example line)

Comment: Please update your question with sample lines from the file. Seems like you might benefit by creating a class to hold the data, which could have the ability to create an instance of itself from a string (file line) and output itself as a string (for writing to a file). Is the format of the line: `"Score: [score] ~[Name] -- Timer: [mm:ss] -- [numCorrect]/41"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a few assumptions since you haven't updated your question, but assuming that the file line contains lines in the format: `"Score: [score] ~[Name] -- Timer: [mm:ss] -- [numCorrect]/41"`, and that `score` is a `double` and `numCorrect` is an `int` (you don't show where they come from), then here's one way to handle this situation.

First, create a class with the properties you want to store that has the ability to create an instance of itself from a string (file line) and output itself as a string (for writing to a file):

```
private class Result
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public int CorrectCount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an instance of the Result class based on a string.
    /// The string must be in the format:
    /// "Score: [score] ~[Name] -- Timer: [mm:ss] -- [numCorrect]/41"
    /// Where [score] is a valid double and [numCorrect] a valid int
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The string to parse</param>
    /// <returns>A Result with properties set from the input string</returns>
    public static Result Parse(string input)
    {
        if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));

        var splitStrings = new[] {"Score:", " ~", " -- ", "/41"};

        var parts = input
            .Split(splitStrings, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(item => item.Trim())
            .ToList();

        // These will hold the converted parts of the string
        double score;
        int correctCount;
        TimeSpan time;

        // Verify that the string contains 4 parts, and that the Score, Time, and
        // CorrectCount parts can be converted to the proper data type for the property
        if (parts.Count != 4 ||
            !double.TryParse(parts[0], out score) ||
            !TimeSpan.TryParseExact(parts[2], @"mm\:ss", 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out time) ||
            !int.TryParse(parts[3], out correctCount))
        {
            throw new FormatException("input is not in a recognized format");
        }

        return new Result
        {
            Name = parts[1],
            Score = score,
            Time = time,
            CorrectCount = correctCount
        };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Score:{Score} ~{Name} -- {Time.ToString(@"mm\:ss")} -- {CorrectCount}/41";
    }
}
```

Then create a method that can create an instance of this class from your form data:

```
// Not sure where these come from so created these class fields
private const string Path = @"f:\public\temp\score.txt";
private double score = 0;
private int numCorrect = 0;

private static Result GetResultFromFormData()
{
    return new Result
    {
        Score = score,
        Name = textBox1.Text,
        Time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(label9.Text, @"mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        CorrectCount = numCorrect)
    };
}
```

Now we can populate a list of these classes from both the file contents and the form. Then we can sort the list using `Linq` on any field we want to (`Score` in this case), and can write the sorted list back to the file:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Submit Button
{
    if (isDone)
    {
        // Create a list of results from our file
        List<Result> existingResults = File.ReadAllLines(Path).Select(Result.Parse).ToList();

        // Add a new result to the list from the form data
        existingResults.Add(GetResultFromFormData());

        // Sort the list on the Score property
        existingResults = existingResults.OrderBy(result => result.Score).ToList();

        // Write the sorted list back to the file
        File.WriteAllLines(Path, existingResults.Select(result => result.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Now the file contains it's original contents, plus the new result from the form, all sorted by `Score`.

Comment: Yup! This works. Sorry for not updating. I have been very busy at work lately and didn't have the time.